# Calcular la media en un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe de la siguiente manera:

| Marca | Modelo | CO2 Em |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Audi | SUB | 10 |
| Audi | A | 15 |
| BMW | SUB | 11 |
| Seat | B | 10 |
| Seat | SUB | 14 |
| Audi | A | 15 |
| BMW | SUB | 11 |
| Audi | B | 10 |

Y necesito calcular en **una única expresión** la media de emisiones C02 para los vehículos del modelo SUB, independientemente de su marca. En este caso sería la media de [10, 11, 14, 11].
Lo que yo estaba realizando es lo siguiente:

```
mean = []
col_names = list(df.columns)

for i in range(len(df)):
    c = {c: df.iloc[i][c] for c in col_names}
    if c['Modelo'] == "SUB":
        mean.append(c['CO2 Em'])
```

así guardaba en mean todos los datos para luego realizar la media de ellos con por ejemplo statistics.

Comment: Si te refieres a la función seria `media = lambda lst: sum(lst)/(len(lst))` simplemente pasa la lista

Comment: Me refiero a que en una linea coja los datos del dataframe y haga la media utilizando por ejemplo .mean()

Comment: `df[df.Modelo == "SUB"].mean()`

Comment: Aunque ya te hayan ayudado en comentarios (cosa que no me gusta mucho, pues equivale a dar una respuesta de muy baja calidad), deberías de demostrar que eres parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propio problema, sea con un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) o haciendo mención de lo que has investigado y/o las paginas que visitaste. De ese modo la comunidad recibirá mejor tu pregunta y no parecera una del tipo "haganme la tarea". Por favor lee [como preguntar](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, soy nuevo en esto y estaba un poco desquiciado

Comment: De nada c: Todos hemos sido nuevos en algo alguna vez nwn

Answer (score 1):

Con esto te debería de ayudar, lo que hago es filtrar por los modelos "SUB" con una máscara y le hago un método mean() de pandas si lo necesitas directamente

```
emisiones_sub = df[df["Modelo"]=="SUB"]["CO2 Em"].mean()
```

Si solo te interesa extraer los valores par apoder hacer más cosas puedes convertirlo a tipo lista con la función built in

```
emisiones_sub = list(df[df["Modelo"]=="SUB"]["CO2 Em"].mean())
```